# How to identify packages added in the @ComponentScan spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

In a large project I am working on, there are lots of packages and components. I want to modularise the project and deploy it as separate war files.

The issue I am facing is that some war files has the Controller which I haven't added in the component scan of the Application. I suspect its been added from some other Configuration file.

Is there any method to identify the list of packages added to Spring component scan. I want to map the dependency and modularise the project so that each war file will only have the required compoents loaded.

Thanks in advance.